# How to work with new iOS Google Maps SDK under no ARC project

Tags: google-maps, ios6, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to add the new Google Maps API into my iOS application, however it does not use ARC yet. So, checking at the docs I think it's a requirement to have ARC in order for the SDK to work. How could I do that? I mean an option would be activating ARC just for the resources that will work with Google maps. (.xib files, controllers) How could that be done?

Comment: Did you arrive a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Yes, just do the reverse. Add -fobjc-arc compiler flag to each source file which needs ARC.

Comment: But I don't have .m file of google map iOS sdk, Then how can I  Add -fobjc-arc compiler flag to each source file? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can disable ARC for individual files by adding a compiler flag **-fno-objc-arc**

This flag tells the compiler that the files are not ARC based.

To do the this

1. Select the target
2. Go to Build Phases tab
3. Expand the Compile Sources
4. Select the files which are not Arc based
5. Press Enter
6. In the appeared dialog box enter the text **-fno-objc-arc**
7. Done

For more reference please check this question [how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: Ok, but is the opposite the same? I mean just activate ARC for the controller that I need. Will I have problems connecting the current xib with the ARC enabled controller? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure whether the reverse is true. for third party libraries you can use **-fno-objc-arc** and for your existing code which is not arc based you could migrate it to arc based code using xcode refactoring, Which works well in most cases. 
xcode -> Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to obj-c arc.